# cant access network share windows server 2008 Domain

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, network-share

I am currently having an issue with one Windows 7 PRO pc(fully up to date windows and drivers) accessing one windows server 2008 share. This particular server 2008 share is accessed by about 20 users that have no issues accessing this share. I can see the file if I browse to the network share via `\\192.168.x.x\share`. 
 When I browse to `\\servername\share` it displays one folder out of 100. I can resolve the server name by I.P. and FQDN. I can see other network shares just fine on this server also. Firewall is off and AV is uninstalled on both servers. This is the case for all users on this pc including domain admins. I have un joined and renamed this pc from the domain as well.

What do I need to look at next?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly the other computers have the maxtokensize registry setting and this computer doesn't - https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/kb/327825

Answer (score 0):

Sharing folders in Windows can have the following issues:

1. Local sharing, they must be on the same Workgroup.
2. Firewall should allow sharing.
3. With Windows 7, you should turn on Network Discovery and File and Printer Sharing. The one in the advanced setting of Network and Sharing.

I'm did clearly get your setup specially since your mentioned *both servers*, meaning you are using the Windows 7 as Server also or to host the shared files? In case you are using Windows 7 to host your shared files, note that Windows 7 has a hard limit of 20 concurrent connections. This is not 20 users but 20 connections. The limit is much lower in previous versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

How strange it may sound, this is actually a solution more people had for the same issue: formatting the CSC cache:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942974

Comment: This is a link only answer ...